# PYTHON/ TKINTER: How to get 2 Labels to be stacked beneath each other

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class Header(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        master.title("Header")

        frame = tk.Frame(master, bg='green')
        frame.pack(fill=tk.X, ipadx=20)

        heading = tk.Label(frame, text = 'Heading', bg="green")
        heading.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N)

        line1_header = tk.Label(frame, text='Paragraph', bg='green')
        line1_header.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N)

root=tk.Tk()
app = Header(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I get these 2 labels to be stacked beneath each other in tkinter?  What is currently happening is the are next to each other.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm

Comment: @fhdrsdg I tried that but it centres the text, I am wanting the text to be pressed to the left, which side=tk.left does

Comment: You can do that with `anchor=tk.W`.